# Need way to keep historical data in lists that uses site column

Tags: 2010, site-column

Just want to preface this with I am just a site curator.  I do not have SharePoint admin rights but can pass suggestions on to the admins.

I created a site column "Sales Person Names" that is referenced in 10 lists.  The site column references a list for all these names.  I am trying to add this site column to already existing lists that have a hard coded list of sales names so I don't have to update each list manually.

Problem I am running into is when a Sales person leaves the team and I want to remove the name from the site column so it cannot be used in new records for each list.  But when I removed the sales person name from the site column it also removes the name in all the lists that it was referenced in.

I want to be able to keep historical data and make it easy to manage the list of sales person names across all lists.  So if Bob the sales guy leaves the team I can still find all the records associated to him and prevent his name from showing up in the "sales person names" field when a new record is created.

Hopefully that explains my issue.
Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: It appears to me that your site column is a look up field?did you consider using people picker for this? maybe use a people picker that is limited to one SharePoint group. then you can just maintain your SharePoint group like what you are doing in the Sales person list.

Comment: I inherited all these lists so I was not involved with their initial creation.  I think using a person/group lookup might be the way to go for new lists but the problem I foresee with current list is with people that have already left the company.  SharePoint will no longer have their name as a person record to put in SharePoint groups so I would not be able to convert the old lists with historical names of people that left the company.  Great idea and I may need to do that with new lists going forward.